# get latest commit for blob with ruby/grit

Tags: ruby, git, grit

i cloned a copy of the git-wiki for some educational programming. now, as a challange, i tried to figure out how to get the date for the blob.

the blob is fetched with

```
repository.tree/(page_name + extension)
```

as far as i saw it, you can only get a date for a commit. but how to get the latest commit containing the blob?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Which commit has this blob?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/git-which-commit-has-this-blob)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
repository.log("master", "app/models/....", :max_count => 5, :skip => 1)
```

then you'll get commits related to the blob. The first param is a branch name and the second is the path of the blod. `:max_count` and `:skip` are optional parameters. Take a look at [grit's rubyforge](http://grit.rubyforge.org/) for more functionality. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150727/how-to-see-the-file-size-history-of-a-single-file-in-a-git-repository) is also helpful.