# Get history of *size* of a file in a Git repository

Tags: git

Is it possible to get the history of the size of a file in a git repo from the command line? Something like the following would be ideal, if it is possible:

```
git foo path/to/my/file.ext
```

output

```
a29847fa    Feb. 5 2016         666 bytes
2ad7eec     Dec. 12 2015        63475 bytes
[etc.]
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150727/how-to-see-the-file-size-history-of-a-single-file-in-a-git-repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see the file size history of a single file in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150727/how-to-see-the-file-size-history-of-a-single-file-in-a-git-repository)