# How can I query the commited files and every file's size at git repository by commit hash?

Tags: git

Now I get the commit hashs are "`366062a075ea62b5874564c5b7216d1f5af58607`" and "`900c273cea298bebcacc077ad4439964b985168d`".

I want to query the committed files and every committed file's size with a commit hash.

Otherwise, I want to query the committed files and every committed file's size with these two commit hash by using just a command.

Are these two needs can be realized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to query the commited files and every commited file's size with these two commit hash by using just a command.

A single command would give you only the list of files (`git show commit_id --name-only`)

For the size, you need at [least a second command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3155268/6309), although you can try and extract from it both (name and size)

```
 git ls-tree -r -l <aCommitID>

 git ls-tree -r -l <aCommitID> | awk '{print $4 " " $5}'
```

Comment: git ls-tree -r -l <aCommitID> help me a lot.Thank you very much!